# Logical expressions not working

Tags: sql, logical-operators

I have SQL statement as below:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tbl_test 
WHERE Carrier='XYZ' 
      && DateTime >= "2014-11-03" 
      && DateTime <= "2014-11-06"
```

What is happening is that the search is returning results only from date 2014-11-03 to 2014-11-05 despite the second logical operation includes date 2014-11-06.

Help is required to guide me where I am possibly going wrong.

Thank you.

Dhyanesh

Comment: Which database engine? (Oracle, MySQL, SQL Server etc)

Comment: Does your date field have a time component?   Because 2014-11-06 00:00:01 would not qualify.

Comment: Why not use the `BETWEEN` keyword?

Comment: DOes `SELECT * FROM tbl_test where Carrier='XYZ' && DateTime >= "2014-11-03" && DateTime < "2014-11-07"` give you the expected results? (added 1 to day and removed = on 2nd date.  the alternative would be to truncate the time part of datetime on the second datetime comparison.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this solve your problem?

```
SELECT *
FROM tbl_test
WHERE Carrier='XYZ' && DateTime >= "2014-11-03" && DateTime < "2014-11-07"
```

The difference is that is this includes the whole last day and not just the 2014-11-06 at 00:00am.

Comment: Hello,

Thank you for your responses. Certainly helped me to gain an insight into the problem. I managed to resolve the issue by modifying the query as below:

SELECT *
FROM tbl_test
WHERE Carrier='XYZ'
  and DateTime between '2014-11-03 00:00' and '2014-11-06 23:59'

Comment: If you're happy with one of the answers please mark it to complete your question.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM tbl_test
WHERE Carrier='XYZ'
  and DateTime between '2014-11-03' and '2014-11-06'
```